# Does low unemployment cause any political or social issue?

Tags: employment

It seems that high unemployment cause a lot of social and political problems. Is the reverse also true i.e does low unemployment cause any political or social issues?

Comment: How much do you consider economic problems to overlap with those, and how indirect you you want to go. For example low unemployment and high job vacancies correlate to higher inter-regional and international immigration, both of which can lead to social and political issues.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with political or social issues? Would for example some businesses having difficulties finding sufficient staff and not being able to offer services in large quantities (one result of low unemployment) a political or social problem?

Answer (score 7):

Of course. It means that **employers cannot find enough staff**.

Arguably in a perfect economy, there is an unemployment of 2% or thereabouts of people who *want and could* work -- that means on average, for every four years on the job the potential employee spends one month **between jobs.** If the pool of potential employees is much smaller, then a new company, or an expanding one, cannot hire the people they need.

Note that various countries have people on the unemployment statistics who are not reasonably able to take a job, and people who could work outside the unemployment statistics. That could be caused by the organization of the welfare and social security systems. People who would not get any benefits do not register as unemployed while they look for a job. Or people must pretend to look for a job even if they are e.g. caring for dependents, or sick themselves, and cannot really hold a full-time job.

Comment: This would often bring up the issue of immigration policy liberalization, yep.

Comment: This hits some economic implications of low unemployment, but it doesn't really connect the dots to the social and political implications this economic situation.

Comment: @ohwilleke, I  would have tought that employers not finding staff (the economic issue) immediately becomes a political one (they clamor for government to do something) and a social one (suffering economy means suffering people). Need I spell that out?

Answer (score 5):

*Labor Union Activity*

Low unemployment is associated with increased activity by labor unions to seek better conditions and wages (such as strikes and threatened strikes). See, e.g., [here](https://www.epi.org/publication/continued-surge-in-strike-activity/).

Politically, [pro-union legislation](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2015/article/pdf/labor-law-highlights-1915-2015.pdf) usually advances most strongly during times of low unemployment, and sometimes is rolled back in times when the labor market is weaker.

The period of sustained low unemployment after World War II was associated with very high levels of labor activity, high levels of unionization, and strengthened national labor laws.

[image]

[image]

*Participation In Work Force*

[Low unemployment tends to bring people into the workforce](https://www.oecd.org/social/labour/33944738.pdf), such as students, retirees and homemakers, who otherwise would have stayed out of the workforce.

Politically, low unemployment tends to favor legislation relaxing the regulation of child labor at the margins. This is occurring [right now](https://www.epi.org/publication/child-labor-laws-under-attack/).

*Immigration*

Low unemployment tends to increase immigration, both documented and undocumented, which in turn can have all manner of societal impacts.

[image]

([Source](https://www.americanimmigrationcouncil.org/sites/default/files/research/Untying_the_Knot_Series_051909.pdf))

Politically, opposition to legislation or [executive branch policies](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24507641?typeAccessWorkflow=login) making it easier to immigrate tends to weaken in times of low unemployment, while political opposition to immigration and tighter enforcement of immigration laws is associated with times of higher unemployment. If low unemployment is specific to certain industries (e.g. health care or high tech industries or farm workers) that are experiencing worker shortages, immigration legislation tends to focus on immigration by workers in those industries.

For example, the period of sustained low unemployment following World War II that was also associated with the Baby Boom and high levels of union activity, was also associated with [the relaxation of restrictions on immigration from Asia and Latin America](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2015/09/30/how-u-s-immigration-laws-and-rules-have-changed-through-history/). Some of that legislation was targeted at medical professionals and farm workers who were in short supply at the time.

*Births, Marriages, And Divorces*

Low unemployment tends to [increase birth rates](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1408975111). Low unemployment is also associated with [higher marriage rates and lower divorce rates](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11207072_The_Impact_of_Unemployment_on_Marriage_and_Divorce). Birth rates, marriage rates, and divorce rates have wide ranging societal and social impacts.

For example, sustained low unemployment rates were an important factor contributing to the "[Baby Boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers)" in the United States.

High working class unemployment associated with [deindustrialization in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deindustrialization), in contrast, was associated with falling marriage rates and increasing divorce rates for working class families.

Politically, this is the time frame (associated with high unemployment for the working class in the U.S.) when ["no fault" divorce laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-fault_divorce), which made getting a divorce easier, spread across the U.S.

Declining marriage rates and increased divorce rates in the U.S. were also associated historically with [the rise of "family values" as a major political rallying cry in the Republican Party in the U.S.](https://www.bostonpoliticalreview.org/post/family-values-in-american-politics-talking-point-or-call-to-action) on a variety of fronts, since the decline of marriage was attributed by many politically active conservatives with declining morality.

Comment: The strikes graph is very difficult to read, as it excludes different amounts in different eras, also it doesn't overlap the unemployment rate (the graph below starts 10 years later and ends 6 years before)

Comment: @EmmanuelMess I don't disagree but couldn't find better ones.

Comment: [Here](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=1eaTC)'s some data, but it doesn't look like FRED has strikes data for the whole period from 1900 to 2022.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess The data isn't hard to find. Pretty, easy to read charts presenting the data, not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Low unemployment usually means that there is a labor shortage. Companies want to hire more employees in order to cover demand for their goods and services. But they can't, because no employees with the required qualifications are available on the labor market. Sure, they could try to poach employees from other companies by offering them more money, but then *those other* companies can't cover their demand anymore.

The result are supply shortages. The demand for certain goods and services can not be fulfilled due to lack of employees. This is especially problematic and can cause political and social issues if it happens in sectors that fulfill basic needs of the population and thus have a low demand elasticity.

There are things the government can do to combat a labor shortage, but those can be pretty unpopular. For example:

- Reduce social security benefits to force more people into the labor market (angering the left, and angering anyone who has good reasons why they are not in the labor market)
- Make immigration easier (angering the right)
- Raise the retirement age (angering the middle-aged)
- Employ fewer people in the public sector (appeasing the "small government" conservatives in the short term, but angering everyone who is going to suffer from lack of government services and government-provided infrastructure in the long term)

Comment: One of the main things the state does to combat employment is actually to hike interest rates or other measures to assault demand for labour in a manner that doesn't increase its price. I'm surprised this isn't in the list of things mentioned, given its prevalence.